# Displaying coordinates depending on canvas scale

Tags: canvas, coordinates, transform, scale

Photo:

https://inlnk.ru/4yjDZm

I have a canvas that is initially the size of the user's screen (shown in purple).

After scaling, the user's screen area takes on the value width*scale, height*scale (shown in red).

We have padding to the left and top edge of the scaled canvas current_screen.x0, current_screen.y0 and to the center of the transformed canvas current_screen.x1, current_screen.y1.

In this case, the coordinates of the cursor position are counted from the upper left corner of the canvas (shown in green).

How to correctly calculate the cursor position relative to the scaled canvas?  When hovering over the coordinate center, the cursor position should always show x = 0, y = 0.

```
function scale() {
        canvas.addEventListener("wheel", onmousewheel, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", onmousewheel, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousewheel, false);
   
        function onmousewheel(event) {
            position.x = event.clientX*scale_factor;
            position.y = event.clientY*scale_factor;
            var delta = event.type === "wheel" ?  event.wheelDelta : -event.detail;
            var increment = delta > 0 ?  1.1 : 0.9;
            scale *= increment;

            current_screen.x0 = (current_screen.x0 - position.x) * increment + position.x;
            current_screen.y0 = (current_screen.y0 - position.y) * increment + position.y;
            current_screen.x1 = (current_screen.x1 - position.x) * increment + position.x;
            current_screen.y1 = (current_screen.y1 - position.y) * increment + position.y;

            cursor.x = Math.floor(DRAW.px_mm((canvas_inner_width/2-(canvas_inner_width-position.x)))/scale);
            cursor.y = -Math.floor(DRAW.px_mm((canvas_inner_height/2-(canvas_inner_height-position.y)))/scale);

            document.getElementsByClassName('x-pointer')[0].innerText = cursor.x;
            document.getElementsByClassName('y-pointer')[0].innerText = cursor.y;
           
            CANVAS.redraw();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },
```